# Error with getline() function with dirent.h

Tags: c++, linux, getline, dirent.h

I'm writing a file to search for keywords in the current directory.  My program keep coming up with an error every time that I run it.  It says:  'error: no matching function for call to 'getline(char [256], std::__cxx11::string&)'

Here is the relevant parts of my code:

```
struct dirent *pent = NULL;
  while (pent = readdir (pdir)){
  string line;
  int lineNum = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    while(std::getline(pent->d_name, line)){
      if (line.find(argv[i])/*!=string::npos*/){
        cout << argv[i] << " found in " << pent << " on line " << lineNum << endl;
      }
    }
    lineNum++;
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to learn more about C++ streams, and read e.g. [this `std::getline` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: You have to open the file first, then pass the stream of the opened file.